# How to free dynamically allocated array in C in a for loop

Tags: c, free

So this is the code I have: my main function calls the readtitles function

```
int main() {
   char **bookTitles;
   bookTitles= malloc(bookCount * sizeof(char*));
   readtitles(bookTitles,  bookCount);

   free(bookTitles);
   return 0;
}
```

and this is my readtitles function:

```
void readtitles(char **bookTitles, int bookCount) {

    int i;

    printf("Enter the book titles: ");

    for(i = 0; i < bookCount; ++i) {
        *(bookTitles+i) = malloc(61*sizeof(char));
        scanf(" %[^\n]",*(bookTitles+i));
    }
}
```

when I use valgrind I get memory leaks how do I go about freeing the memory in a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop over the array and `free` it. After that, you can `free` the array of pointers:

```
int i;
for( i = 0; i < bookCount; i++ )
    free(bookTitles[i]);
free(bookTitles);
```